# git pushes repository successfully but files don't upload to remote server

Tags: git

I am newbie to git system and trying to set up git system (using git-scm) between my local computer (OS: Windows) and server (server provider: hostinger.com). I don't want any middle man like github or other servers.

To test my git system, i have created a new repository, added a test file to it, committed, and pushed it to remote bare repository, all with no error. However, my test file doesn't show up on server, there is just bare repository folder on the server. I have done all git commands on same bash to show you results:
[image]

The only thing that is not on the picture is, I uploaded a simple "new 1.txt" file to d:/wamp64/www/test/ location manually after using "git init" command. As a result, there is just "wp.git" folder on the server but not "new 1.txt" file. What am I missing?

Comment: On your local computer there is the working tree (the files you are working on) and the repository in the `.git` subdirectory. The working tree contains the files of the commit that are currently checked out. You created a bare repository on the server (and this is the right way to do it). A bare repository does not have a working tree. To check that the remote repository contains your files make a new clone of the remote repository into a new local directory, checkout the branch and inspect the files in the working tree.

Comment: Attention! Git is not appropriate as a deploy mechanism.

Comment: @axiac thanks for the warning, figured out it is really bad idea for deploy mechanism. I just wanted sync live server (which runs wordpress e-commerce) to local pc, make necessary developments and sync changed files back to server. Doing it manually is really hard. Do you have any suggestion for this job? For now, i am planning to use "rsync" to synron my local pc and server and use git to develop on local.

As final, I understand that, bare repo took changes from my local repo but doesn't create a working tree (basically doesn't create the files). Is there an easy way to create it at remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I had the wrong ideas about git system. For the newbies trying to do what i was trying:

```
ssh u266881589@194.5.156.43 -p 65002 "git clone /home/u266881589/domains/mezegurmanams.lt/public_html/wp.git /home/u266881589/domains/mezegurmanams.lt/public_html/test"
```

Adding this last command does the trick for me, however it is not what i really want. As I have learnt, Git is not appropriate for deployment or to sync files like i was trying to do. Especially for binary files like image files etc. it becomes another problem. Conclusion, using git for just development and something like "rsync" to synchronize files is a better solution